# How to disable the Win10 powershell?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, windows-10

I just got VAC disconnected during a competitive match and I don't know why. It's the first time that this happened.

Looking at the [Disconnected by VAC: You cannot play on secure servers](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2117-ilzv-2837#software) docs, I see that one of the programs that are not allowed is **PowerShell**.

How do you disable/uninstall PowerShell so I don't get disconnected again, or even banned?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro, version: 1607.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't have PowerShell active and running while you're playing, you're fine and the issue is somewhere else. PowerShell is basically a fancy CMD and COULD be used to tamper with the game and inject stuff (hacks). I'm going to go ahead and assume you didn't have PowerShell running while playing, because you'd have to be the one starting PowerShell, so that's not the issue.

Moreover PowerShell is part of Windows; as I said, it's a fancy CMD (hopefully you know what that is, you have 10k on OF, you know what that is :D) and you can't exactly get rid of it that easily.

Just in case do a Ctrl+Shift+Esc and check if its in there in the list, and if it is - Right Click -> End Task.

If this is the first time you get disconnected like so and this has not happened before while you were playing, try restarting your Computer.
If this doesn't work, check out your most recently installed apps. Most likely one of those is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have it on. I just started playing CS:GO, have about 74 hours and my competitive rank is MG2 (I played CS 1.6. a lot). I really don't know why it happened - until now I had no issues so I presumed that it's because of PowerShell. So I don't have to worry? That's a relief :D

Comment: No, unless you're consciously hacking, with a sfoftware that uses pwoershell then, no you're fine and the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Don't have anything, it's just me and my AK47 :P 
Thanks for the info. Cheers :)

Comment: "Power Shell is basically a fancy CMD" This is a *vast* oversimplification...

Comment: @jpmc26 it is, but in our case and in the name of being understood its not that far off.

Comment: What does OF stand for? Could you write out the acronym in full so that we know what you are talking about? Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was meant for OP, OverFlow as in stackoverflow

Comment: @ИвоНедев: Ah. That's properly rendered "Stack Overflow", or "SO" for short.